# Set default theme on load in JS localStorage until theme is selected by user

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm looking for a way to set the color theme of my site as the preset 'theme-dark-purple' until visitors select their preferred color theme from a menu I've created. Right now, everything works except for the piece below, that is meant to set the theme without a visitor doing it (when you load my page for the first time, the color theme disappears and everything but the images are white). I've had to put a popup warning directing new visitors to chose their theme, and it's terrible for user experience.

```
<script>
  (function () {
    const themes = ['theme-dark-purple', 'theme-light-purple', 'theme-dark-blue', 'theme-light-blue', 'theme-dark-green', 'theme-light-green', 'theme-black-gold', 'theme-light-yellow', 'theme-dark-orange', 'theme-light-orange', 'theme-dark-red', 'theme-light-red'];
    if (!themes.includes(localStorage.getItem('theme'))) {
      setTheme('theme-dark-purple');
    }
  })();
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emrysmayell/4av9uo2w/1/#&togetherjs=3bqlb26HNN

Comment: Can you please explain the code what is it supposed to do? as it currently seems to work if you do localstorage.setItem('theme', 'theme-dark-purple'), i think i am missing something int the question?

Comment: @DeepinderSingh I know, it's weird. The code seems like it's supposed to work but it doesn't. You didn't miss anything, it's supposed to set the default theme on load but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it and pass it on, let's check if we can re generate?

Comment: Alright I've never shared a Fiddle before but I pasted the link in the question. Let me know if it works.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mqc3awrn/ this is working perfectly and storing the same, are you sure there isn't anything else breaking your code in your repo that it is unable to execute this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Your code set theme to default only if nothing is stored in the `localStorage`. This will set it to saved otherwise to default:

```
(function () {
  const themes = ['theme-dark-purple', 'theme-light-purple', 'theme-dark-blue', 'theme-light-blue', 'theme-dark-green', 'theme-light-green', 'theme-black-gold', 'theme-light-yellow', 'theme-dark-orange', 'theme-light-orange', 'theme-dark-red', 'theme-light-red'];

  setTheme(themes[themes.indexOf(localStorage.getItem('theme'))] || 'theme-dark-purple');
})();
```

Comment: That's actually what I want. If localStorage has a theme in it, I want the site to set that theme. And I have separate code for that. This code is meant to set 'theme-dark-purple' only if there's no theme in localStorage.

Comment: Than what is your question? You provide no other code that we can evaluate...Your example works exactly as you wanted it to.